# S3 java client update object metadata without creating a new version

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have versioning enabled in my bucket, and when I update only metadata of a s3 object using CopyObjectRequest S3 create me a new version of the file with the new metadata, but I don't want this.
How can I just edit metadata without creating a new version and without disabling versioning ?

I am using S3 Java 2 sdk

```
CopyObjectRequest request = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
        .sourceBucket("myBucketName")
        .sourceKey("myObjectKey")
        .destinationBucket("myBucketName")
        .destinationKey("myObjectKey")
        .metadata(newMetadata)
        .metadataDirective(MetadataDirective.REPLACE)
        .build();
```